# Rmarkdown does not recognize pandoc filter

Tags: filter, latex, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

I would like to call a pandoc filter ([this one](https://github.com/NMarkgraf/typography.py)) from rmarkdown/RStudio. However, pandoc seems not to recognize the filter. I've handed over the filter in the YAML header. Consider this `rmd` file:

```
---
title: "test"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{xspace}
pandoc_args:
    - --filter
    - pandoc-filter/typography.py
---

test  
s.S.
```

The knitting output shows no sign that the filter was handed over to pandoc:

`/usr/local/bin/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS test_typography-py.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output test_typography-py.pdf --template /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmd/latex/default-1.17.0.2.tex --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine pdflatex --variable graphics=yes --variable 'geometry:margin=1in'`

The rendered pdf file does not show the effects of the filter, see image [image]

(The effect of the filter is to render a thin space between phrases such as "z.B." or "e.g.".)

What can I do to get this filter run by pandoc via rmarkdown (preferably using the YAML header)?

Answer (score 3):

I just realized (thanks to @NMarkgraf) that I had an intendation error. The correct intendation in YAML is this:

```
---
title: "test"
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{xspace}
output: 
  pdf_document:
    pandoc_args:
      - --filter
      - typography.py
---
```

Then it works - the filter is recognized.